# Angular how to avoid flash of default theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

So, I've Implemented a angular service to toggle the theme and it is working pretty well but it is suffering from flash of wrong theme.

My current implementation checks local storage for stored preference if no preference exists it will check the os color preference and apply that.

I've read that you can avoid the flash by running the dark mode code in the head of the html
how can I initialize the angular service in the head or are there any other methods to prevent the flash of wrong theme from happening.

Answer (score 2):

One way of approaching this would be to use Angular's [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) InjectionToken to resolve some data before the app begins to respond.

You could do something like:

**app.module.ts**

```js
function loadTheme(themeService: ThemeService) {
  return () => themeService.loadTheme();
}

// in your app.module providers array
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: loadTheme,
    deps: [ThemeService],
    multi: true
  }
]
```

Note that APP_INITIALIZER in this situation is expecting a resolved promise or Observable to be returned from the ThemeService's `loadTheme()` method. The linked Angular docs have an example of how to use a resolved Promise.